# Yii2 GridView widget not displaying data

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a view where I'm trying to output data:

```
echo GridView::widget ( [ 
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [ 
                    [ 
                            'label' => 'Contact',
                            'attribute' => 'clientcontactrole',
                            'value' => 'clientcontactrole.contactAsHTML',
                            'format' => 'raw' 
                    ],
```

... etc. The problem I'm having is that none of the fields are displaying, even though they're in the database and should be being fetched in the model by:

```
public function getContactAsHTML() {
        return Html::a($this->contact, [
                'contact/view/',
                'id' => $this->id]);
    }
```

...etc. Is this a problem in my view, or in the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I fixed it, the problem was actually in the controller, where the 'dataProvider' I was using was being specified as something else. I've created a sort of 'hacky' fix for now where I instantiate a new dataProvider inside the actual view, and now I can get it to display the data.